# Sublime Text 3 Multi Selection and Delete

Tags: select

Good morning.
I am on Windows10. I am really in crisis. In a file I have to multi select and delete all the ''>'' and ''<'' characters. Is it possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can select what you want and then use CTRL+D to select the multiple things you want.

You can even go further by using regex (with CTRL+F)